# React Native Expo: read/write external files

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I wanted to know if/how it's possible to read/write non-app files with Expo. I specifically need to access files that fall outside of the app's directory, such as the downloads folder, images folder, and any other external folder. Expo docs on FileSystem say that it is only able to access app files, and not external files.

Comment: Could you clarify? It is possible to use a PDF in your downloads folder and get that file to for example send it via mail.

Comment: @yesIamFaded specifically I need to be able to read/move/delete files. First I prompt the user to select a folder, and then the app deletes some files from that folder, and moves some of the files to different folders. Additionally I need to preview some of the files in the app